# Data from selector to slow for FormBuilder

Tags: angular, forms, ngrx, formbuilder

I want to be able to edit existing data from database in an reactive form. I'm using a selector to get the data from the store (Ngrx), but the problem is that the component render the form even though the data has not been loaded yet.

I have struggled with this, the data is displayed if i do a timeout before calling 'createEditForm', but everything crashes in the background because there is no data in the beginning..

Is there any good solution to skip rendering the form until the variable ev$ is not 'undefiened'...

The error message right now is *'EventEditComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.*'

And a lots of *'TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EventEditComponent.html:10)'*

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'ex-event-edit',
      templateUrl: './event-edit.component.html',
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      styleUrls: ['./event-edit.component.scss'],
    })
    export class EventEditComponent implements OnInit {
      ev$: Observable<Event>;
      eventEditForm: FormGroup;
      eventId: number;
      starttime: Date;
      endtime: Date;
      fileUpload: File = null;
      imageUrl: string;

      constructor(
        private store$: Store<AppState>,
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private actionsSubject$: ActionsSubject
      ) {
        dateAdapter.setLocale('sv');
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
          this.eventId = params['id'];
        });

        this.store$.dispatch(new fromEvents.LoadEvent(+this.eventId)); //Load specific event to the state
        this.ev$ = this.store$.pipe(select(fromEvents.getCurrentEvent)); //Get the specific event

        setTimeout(() => { //Bad solution, but the only way to display the data in the component....
          this.createEventEditForm();
        }, 300);
      }

      createEventEditForm() {
        this.ev$.subscribe((ev) => {
          this.eventEditForm = this.fb.group(
            {
              id: [ev.id],
              title: [ev.title, Validators.required],
              description: [ev.description, Validators.required],
              image: [null],
              location: [ev.location, Validators.required],
              startdate: [new Date(ev.startDate), Validators.required],
              enddate: [new Date(ev.endDate), Validators.required],
            },
            { validator: this.DateValidation }
          );
          this.starttime = ev.startDate;
          this.endtime = ev.endDate;
          this.eventId = ev.id;
          this.imageUrl = ev.image;
        });
      }
```

-HTML-

```html
    <form *ngIf="ev$; else stillLoading" [formGroup]="eventEditForm" (ngSubmit)="updateEvent()" >
      <button [disabled]="!eventEditForm.dirty || !eventEditForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn- 
      success">Save changes</button>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="title">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Change title</mat-label>
          <mat-error *ngIf="eventEditForm.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage('title') }}</mat-error>
          <input class="title" type="text" matInput formControlName="title" autocomplete="off"  />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      </div>

    ....more code but it's similar to the code above
    </form>

    <ng-template #stillLoading>
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that reactive forms work instantly when ngrx is asynchronous.
To solve the issue you need to split your code into two components: smart and dumb.

The dumb one should have the form and an `@Input` for the form data (an object, not an observable). You can implement `OnChange` interface to update the form state based on the new input value.

The smart one dispatches the action to load the data, selects it from the store and passes to the input of the dumb component like that

```html
<form-component [data]="ev$ | async"></form-component>
```